# How to get the signature of a callable type?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++17, template-meta-programming

I want to build a nice, modern interface for building a computation tree, something like this:

```
auto [F, G] = calcs.emplace(
        [](int a, int b){ return a + b; },
        [](){ return 4; }
    );
```

I got the inspiration from [taskflow](https://github.com/cpp-taskflow/cpp-taskflow), but here we might add arguments and return types as well, and here comes the problem: How can we deduce the type of the underlying storage for the given *Callable* objects, and how to store them in a collection? Is it possible to create such a simple api with the current language features at all?

I googled for that for hours and it looks like the return type is the smaller issue, but I have no idea for the arguments.

Comment: You won't get one type, you have one type per signature, and you can store these in `std::function<>`.

Comment: You're going to need to elaborate a lot on what it is you want this to actually do and how you expect it to work. What do you want to do with your callables that take different numbers of arguments?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher But you can't store different `std::function` template instantiations in the same collection (without another level of type erasure).

Comment: Yes indeed, I thought that was obvious :p

Comment: "method_traits" uses signature from `&C::operator()`, but requires only 1 non template `operator ()`...

Comment: Can you show more complete usage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** How to get signature?

**A:** By pattern matching on `operator()` method of the callable, for example:

```
template <class TMethodType>
struct ReadSignature;

// Const specialization
template <class TReturnType, class TClass, class ... TArgsTypes>
struct ReadSignature<TReturnType(TClass::*)(TArgsTypes...) const> {
    using ReturnType = TReturnType;
    using Class = TClass;
    using Args = std::tuple<TArgsTypes...>;

    static constexpr bool is_const = true;
};

// Non-const specialization
// This is for mutable lambdas, e.g. []() mutable {}
template <class TReturnType, class TClass, class ... TArgsTypes>
struct ReadSignature<TReturnType(TClass::*)(TArgsTypes...)> {
    using ReturnType = TReturnType;
    using Class = TClass;
    using Args = std::tuple<TArgsTypes...>;

    static constexpr bool is_const = false;
};
```

You use it like this:

```
    auto callable = [](int x, int y) { return x + y; };
    using Class = decltype(callable);
    using Signature = ReadSignature<decltype(&Class::operator())>;
```

**Q:** How to store callables in a collection?

**A:** You'll need to erase types one way or another. For callable objects making a wrapper interface seems natural. For example, something like this:

```
class CallableI {
    virtual ~CallableI() = default;

    virtual std::any call(const std::vector<std::any>& args) = 0;

    // For type checking:
    virtual size_t arg_count() = 0;
    virtual std::type_info get_arg_type_info(size_t arg_index) = 0;
    virtual std::type_info get_return_type_info() = 0;
};
```

Then you write a template class that implements this interface which will be instantiated for each lambda argument. In your `calcs` object you actually store `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CallableI>>`.